# Handsfree single button press does not open Google Voice in my app anymore

Tags: android

I have own app, where I use Google for voice input.
I use it in two ways - I have an icon on the screen which I tap and I get the dialog of Google Voice and I speak. The same happens when I have connected earphones and I do a single press of the button. The second one worked just naturally, I did not code it. This is what is run when I press the button on the screen:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
    RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Voice your answer");
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

After a recent Google App and Play Services, this does not happen anymore. Any idea how to solve it and be able to launch the mic again with the headset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by this we can detect handsfree button clicked! TRY IT

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
     if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK){
         //handle click
         return true;
     }
     return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
```

}

MAY BE HELP YOU!!

Comment: happy coding !!